# Do all applications under an IIS website have access to each others cookies?

Tags: iis, dns

I understand that applications under the same domain name can talk to each other thru cookies. But how does this translate at the IIS level? Do all these applications have to be under the same IIS website, for them to be able to to read each other's cookies? I believe the isolation level chosen for the application pool also plays a role.

SO the short version of this question is, in IIS, what does it take, to make to separate web applications, to be able to read each others cookies?

This is a purely theoretical question.

Update: After further reading up on cookies it seems like when you set the cookie you can also specify which domains it should be available to. (for instance I can create a cookie available to everyone by setting the domain as .com) If thats true, IIS configuration has nothing to do with the accessibility of the cookie?

Comment: This question seems similar to another: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269354/is-it-possible-to-access-cookies-which-exists-on-another-application-in-iis

Comment: I did check that link. But it doesn't exactly address my query :(

Comment: Try this one: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie access has nothing to do with the IIS setting. The code that sets the cookie decides who (requests from the same domain or all domains) has access to the cookie.